# How to insert the font awesome icon into an input button like this?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code but I can't insert the icon in the middle of the button?

Please see here: http://jsfiddle.net/fsbqv3z4/

```
<input type="button" id="google-search" name="btnI" formaction="https://www.google.com/search?q=adprizes%2B+" class="searchButton2" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="&nbsp;Pesquisar"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **button** tag instead of **input** because in that way, you can use any text ,image or anything inside it like in following code.

```
<button id="google-search" name="btnI" formaction="https://www.google.com/search?q=adprizes%2B+" class="searchButton2" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="&nbsp;Pesquisar"><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg"></i></button>
```

But if you are going to use **input** then image tag **i** will not come inside that button.

Comment: With your code the button is perfect but when submitting it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiGqr.jpg ... But it should appear like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaKkE.jpg

Comment: Attention, after all it works but we have to click outside the icon image. I wonder why?

Answer (score 1):

```
<button id="google-search" name="btnI" formaction="https://www.google.com/search?q=adprizes%2B+" class="searchButton2" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="&nbsp;Pesquisar"> <i class="fa fa-times fa-lg"></i></button>
```

Can you try this? I hope it help you)

Comment: So it works but then it doesn't send the data correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply change the `<input>` to an `<a>` tag, and change `formaction` to `href`? Seem to be the rational solution here. The anchor need to have added the `.btn` class :

```html
<a id="google-search" name="btnI" href="https://www.google.com/search?q=adprizes%2B+" class="btn searchButton2" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="&nbsp;Pesquisar">
<i class="fa fa-times fa-lg"></i>
</a>
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/afuhvp1g/**

Note: The link will never work form within jsfiddles iframe due to `sameorigin`.

Comment: With your code the button is perfect but when submitting it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiGqr.jpg ... But it should appear like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaKkE.jpg

Comment: Then you have may some bad settings for your server, localhost, webapp or whatever Are you using any kind of routing? Inserting the markup in a random page on a Apache server gives the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex-box to position items
For eg : if you want to position anything inside a button in the middle you can use the below css

```css
 .searchButton2{
      display:flex;
      align-items:center;
      justify-content:center;
      max-width: 130px;
      width: 50px;
      height: 45px;
      border: 3px solid red;
      background: #28b9ed;
      text-align: center;
      color: #fff;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-size: 14px;
      outline: none;
    }
```

```html
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<button type="button" id="google-search" name="btnI" formaction="https://www.google.com/search?q=adprizes%2B+" class="searchButton2" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="&nbsp;Pesquisar"> 
<i class="fa fa-search"  aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: but it appears like this

Comment: i think u missed something how does it appear ?

Comment: because font awesome is not included...., does not really need flex....

Comment: @user1856464 you can check it now

Comment: But where will I check?

Comment: It works well but we have to click outside the icon image area. I wonder why?